# Node app is not reachable on EC2 insrance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have deployed simple nodejs application on EC2 instance and modified all inbound rules to made port publicly accessible but even after that I am unable to access application.

below is my app:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const log = require('./logger');

const app = express();

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
 
    res.send("Happy logger");
 
 });

app.listen(2000,() => console.log("App is  listening"));
```

Below is my inbound rules settings
[image]

When I am hitting on `ec2-3-82-196-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com:2000` url its showing below error.

[image]

Someone let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: When I go to that URL, I see "Happy longer." Seems like it's working. I do see the "Not Seccure" warning, but that's to be expected because you haven't configured an SSL certificate.

Comment: but its not showing up for me Can you put screenshot plz

Comment: That's wonder on my mobile  phone thats url is working but on desktop browser its not.

Comment: make sure that chrome isn't forcing the HTTPS protocol on URLs. Make sure the URL starts with HTTP://

Comment: I can see the same error you do in chrome when I prefix the URL with HTTPS:// rather than HTTP://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot, you are accessing HTTPS in Chrome:

```
https://ec2-3-82-196-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com:2000.
```

As the commenter suggested, should use HTTP instead (make sure you see the 'Not secure' sign):

http://ec2-3-82-196-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com:2000

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same problem here.

I tried both HTTP and HTTPS, but no use. The app is working in the localhost (A windows 2022 server).

URLS:

https://ec2-3-110-102-41.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080

http://ec2-3-110-102-41.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080

Security Inbound Rules:
[Inbound Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yfxx.png)

NodeJS Code:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
    origin: "*"
}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Hello" });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log("Server listening on port::::::::::::::::::::::\n", PORT);
});
```

Comment: Have you opened the 8080 port in your security group inbound rule as its shown in the screenshot of my question.

Comment: It's a comment, not an answer. Be sure to read [docs here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Digvijay I opened the 8080 port in the inbound rules. You can find it in the attached screenshot of my answer. 

I don't have access to upload the images directly. I allowed uploading images as a link in the answer.

Comment: Might be because of firewall you are unable to access your application at port 8080 to allow your app run at 8080 do `sudo ufw allow 8080/tcp` in your EC2 instance.

Comment: Mine is a windows server.